# filter data using dropdown?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have an array of objects which are just items. I also have a dropdown which I would like to use to allow the user to filter by price or rating however on page load there should be no filtering.

How do I map item data to filter based on the current select option?

I have a plunkr to get started: [LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/ODvBgtc35bAXlhMV8Flx?p=preview)

Comment: Please click "Save" in your plunk and update your question with new URL. You've posted to a gist with empty AngularJS plunk.

Comment: Sorry plunkr has been behaving strangely today. Try now

Comment: A detail blog with example: http://goo.gl/XYmwkr

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First and foremost, your select values are ambiguous. They contain values that can filter AND sort the entries - Separate the two since they are two different functionality.

Next, you need to define a custom Filter which will filter the data based on the rating selected. For this, you enhance the filtering criteria with the "Rating" property to associate the rating selected with a rating value.

Finally, associate the sorting with a predicate and a reverse value - the predicate determines the property / column to determine for the sort (price in your case) while the reverse determines the ascending / descending nature of the sort.

The entire code can be found here - http://plnkr.co/edit/n7TebC?p=preview

I have updated the plunkr and introduced comments so let me know if you do not understand a code.

Comment: This isn't a custom filter as Angular uses that term but it does work like that.