# Filters aren't applied when data comes from $http

Tags: json, angularjs

This is kind of a next-step from [filter data using dropdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958636/filter-data-using-dropdown), and callmekatootie's answer-plunk (http://plnkr.co/edit/n7TebC). Taking that and a few other things, I've got two dropdowns that can act together/apart to filter the data set, and I've applied a limit so it'll only show 4 (and then four more on ng-click, etc). The current plunk is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Sc283f.

If I set the data inside the scope (no $http), and turn off the quantity limit, the two filters work perfectly.

If I add the limit first, like this:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="item in data | limitTo:quantity | filter:customFilter">
```

then it's giving me the first 4 items in data and then applying the filter, which in some cases gets me nothing. But if I reverse that and get the data first:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="item in data | filter:customFilter | limitTo:quantity">
```

the limit only works the first time. Change either filter and the limit no longer seems to apply regularly/correctly/something.

And if I change the data to come in via $http, none of it works. I just get the entire set, no filter, no limit. I could probably live with and/or figure out a way around and/or eventually fix the first two issues (the filters and the limit) but I just can't see any reason why the filters/limit work (mostly) when the data is local, but fail when the data's coming in through $http.

I'm sure I'm missing something really obvious and simple, but hell if I know. Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test data is an array of animals...

```
[
  { animal : 'dog', color : 'blue'},
  { animal : 'cat', color : 'red'}
]
```

But the JSON downloaded by `$http` is an object with an animal in each property...

```
{
  "0": {"title": "...", "animal": "dog", "color": "purple"},
  "1": {"title": "...", "animal": "cat", "color": "yellow"}
}
```

Angular's built in filter only accepts arrays, which is why it's being bypassed when you give it an object instead.

You can change the service to return an array, or you can transform the data to an array when returned from `$http` with a function like this...

```
function toArray(data) {
  var items = [];
  angular.forEach(data, function (value) {
    items.push(value);
  });
  return items;
}

$http.get('demo.json').success(function(data) {
  $scope.data = toArray(data);
});
```

[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jhgAWPzWAqktyRuc34ZY?p=preview)

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhh! I didn't even realize that. Thank you for the explanation!